# Имитация действий пользователя

Tags: php

Всем привет. Можно ли через php взаимодействовать с DOM сайта? Т.е. как написать скрипт, чтобы он заходил на n-страницу авторизации, вводил туда нужные значения, нажимал на кнопку авторизации и выполнял нужные действия на странице? Какие есть библиотеки, где можно об этом почитать?

Comment: Нельзя. Нажатие  на кнопку отрабатывает js в браузере.

Answer (score 1):

смотрите в сторону http://phantomjs.org/
он запускает движок webkit для рендеринга страниц, т.е по сути реальный браузер, 
позволяя делать все то, что может сделать юзер.

Comment: Можно ли в нем сделать такую функцию: заходим на n-сайт - авторизируемся - делаем 1 действие - выходим?

Comment: Да, это можно сделать.

Answer (score 0):

Как вариант, можно попробовать [Selenium](http://www.seleniumhq.org/) — это система для автоматического тестирования сайтов. Она записывает Ваши действия, после чего позволяет их проигрывать многократно.

Comment: Можно ли в нем сделать такую функцию: заходим на n-сайт - авторизируемся - делаем 1 действие - выходим?

Comment: @Alexxosipov да, это можно сделать.

Comment: @Alexxosipov А почему нет? Эта система может повторить всё, что Вы сами можете сделать на сайте.